# Cannot use socket object in controller

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new in `socket.io`,  and I am trying to push specific data to different client-end base on their information in database. I did a very simple practice with `socket.io`:

```

````
//app.js
const Koa = require(‘koa');
const router = require('koa-router')();
const server = require('koa-static');
const app = new Koa();
const http = require('http').createServer(app.callback());
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(server(__dirname + '/'));

app.use(require('./controller')());

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

//each client just take its specific information
socket.on('messge', (msg) => {
  io.to(socket.id).emit('message', socket.id);
});

})



app.io = io; //trying to let controller use 'io' by 'app.io'

http.listen(9000);
```
````

The code above works well, at least those clients side just get their `socket.id` and do not emit to others.
But all the main data handlings are in controller, so I use `app.io=io` to pass `socket.io` to controllers.
When I use `io` in controller:

````
```
//a_controller.js
let fnTestSocketIO = async(ctx, next) => {
    let socketIO = ctx.app.io;

//just use like in the app.js, but process doesn't go in this part
socketIO.on('message', (socket) => {
    console.log('id', socket.id);
});
ctx.response.body = "response from 'test socket.io'";

}
...
module.exports = {
    "GET /test/socket-io": fnTestSocketIO,
}
````

```
Unfortunately, `socketIO.on(...)` does not work.

#### Expected behaviour

1. yarn start
2. `io` in `app.js` can emit message if the client emit `message`.
3. But no things show from the `io` when I send request in the api `/test/socket-io`. (It can response, but not go thorugh `socketIO.on(...)`)

#### Setup

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- browser: Google Chrome 58
- socket.io version: 1.7.3

#### Other information (e.g. stacktraces, related issues, suggestions how to fix)

I can use:

````
```
//a_controller.js

let fnTestSocketIO = async(ctx, next) => {
    let socketIO = ctx.app.io;

    socketIO.emit('message', 'something');    

    ctx.response.body = "response from 'test socket.io'";

}

```
````

to emit, but it will send data to all clients.
I think I need socket ids to send data,  so I tried:

````
```
//a_controller.js
let sid = null;
for(let id in socketIO.sockets.sockets) {
    sid = id;
}
```
````

to get socket's id, however, it is a bad practice obviously.

Are there any hits for this? Thank you so much.